# Watson TTS doesn't allow to choose voice

Tags: text-to-speech, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

Created a Bluemix app to get the proper credentials and using Fiddler Text to Speech(TTS) to record prompts. Recordings use the default "Michael" voice. I want Allison.

If I try passing in "voice", I get the following error, even when I specify "Michael" as my choice:

```
{
  "code_description": "Bad request",
  "code": 400,
  "error": "The argument(s) [u'voice'} are not allowed."
}
```

This is my payload:

```
{
"text": "Hello,, this is Dora. How are you today?",
"voice": "en-US_AllisonVoice"
}
```

I have a developer account, do I need to sign up to use "voice"? Even if I pass in the default "Michael"?

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is in the way you are specifing the `voice` parameter.
The `voice` and `text` parameters can be send as query parameters in a GET.

#### Examples

**1. Curl**

```
curl -u "{username}":"{password}" "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize?voice=en-US_AllisonVoice&text=Hello%2C%20this%20is%20Dora.%20How%20are%20you%20today%3F"
```

**Node**

```
var watson = require('watson-developer-cloud');
var fs = require('fs');

var text_to_speech = watson.text_to_speech({
  username: '<username>',
  password: '<password>',
  version: 'v1'
});

var params = {
  text: 'Hello, this is Dora. How are you today?',
  voice: 'en-US_AllisonVoice',
  accept: 'audio/wav'
};

// Pipe the synthesized text to a file
text_to_speech.synthesize(params).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output.wav'));
```

See the Text to Speech [API Reference](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/text-to-speech/api/v1/#synthesize) for more examples on how to call the service.
Try the example above here:

```
https://text-to-speech-demo.mybluemix.net/api/synthesize?voice=en-US_AllisonVoice&text=Hello%2C%20this%20is%20Dora.%20How%20are%20you%20today%3F
```

*Powered by the demo app: https://text-to-speech-demo.mybluemix.net*

Comment: Thank you, German. I don't have curl installed so I tried to follow the instructions in the Watson TTS demo (read the curl command and tried to reproduce it). I added the accept as a header in fiddler, did the basic authentication using the credentials provided by Bluemix. I listened to the demo and know that Allison works, I just don't seem to be able to call it from Fiddler. But I realize from you answer that I should be able to - I tried Fiddler only as a proof-of-concept (sort of). I'll just code the app up and see how it works there. Thank you!